# How to crop a mp3 in ASP.NET + C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, mp3, crop

I am in an ASP.NET project using C#. The users can upload their MP3 (I have no control over the encoding) and specify a sample size and a sample starting point. On save, the system needs to create a sample of this MP3 based on the information provided.

So the question is: How can Icrop a mp3 in ASP.NET + C#??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you could possibly use a .NET audio library to do this, I think the easiest way to do this would be to run a command like [`FFMpeg`](http://ffmpeg.org) or [`MPlayer`](http://mplayerhq.hu) to do the cropping for you, then send the file back down the line.

For example, with FFMpeg, you can do something like this (from [here](http://tuttodebian.blogspot.com/2008/06/using-ffmpeg-to-cut-mp3-files.html) crops up to the 90th second):

```
ffmpeg -ss 90 -i input.mp3 output.mp3
```

To start FFMpeg, use something like this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
Response.Write("Cutting MP3...");
Response.Flush();
p.StartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("ffmpeg.exe", "-s 90 -i " + inputFile + " " + outputFile);
p.Start();
p.WaitForExit();
Response.Write("Done");
```

The only problem is that it takes quite a while and it's hard to report progress back to the user.

Comment: Thanks a lot this is really helpful! I guess I could run it as a thread somewhere on the server since the user doesn't need to know when it's over. How complicated is it to set up FFMpeg ?

Comment: The main thing you need to do is download `ffmpeg.exe` and put it in a convenient folder somewhere. Then just replace the `ffmpeg.exe` in the example with the path to the where you put the EXE. It's basically one EXE and, IIRC, a DLL.

The biggest problem is actually getting the right command-line arguments as FFMpeg is a *huge* program - when I've used it I've spent quite a lot of time looking through the man pages.

Comment: It worked, thanks. I ran into some issues, addressed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390559/how-to-get-the-output-of-a-system-diagnostics-process http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390731/how-to-crop-a-mp3-from-x-to-xn-using-ffmpeg

Comment: Neat. I thought that that question seemed a bit familiar... :D

Answer (score 0):

You can split the file using the MP3 frame headers.
Using a simple brute force search you can split the file into separate frames and create a new MP3 that is as long as you wish.

[MP3 Format](http://www.mpgedit.org/mpgedit/mpeg_format/mpeghdr.htm)