# Monitor output of a command prompt in C#

Tags: c#, shell, command-line

Is there a way to monitor the output of a command prompt without redirecting its output to a stream reader so that it can be detected if error messages display in it? I'm using C#.

Comment: Just to confirm, you definitely mean a command prompt?  I.e. the interactive `cmd.exe` program where user can enter commands?  Not just another application that has stdin, stdout?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390559/how-to-get-the-output-of-a-system-diagnostics-process

Comment: Yup, a cmd.exe with additional input parameters concerned with env variables etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer: No.

If you need the console output of a program you have to redirect its output stream.

Comment: That is a lie. If process is attached to cmd console It will receive console output and will be able to display text on It.

Comment: And how do you attach a process to a cmd console? By redirecting its input and output streams. So where is the lie?

Answer (score 1):

You must use AttachConsole for cmd.exe process.