# In C# verify the ping utility

Tags: c#

From C# console application i had open the command prompt and checked the ping utility.

```
string aptracommand;
aptracommand = "/C ping 10.38.2.73";
Process.Start(@"cmd",aptracommand);
```

Now , i need to apply a conditional statement if ping request time out then it should say "Not able to connect" and if its able to ping then need to show "Server is up"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use Ping class for this purpose. As stated below:

```
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;

var ping = new Ping();
var reply = ping.Send("10.38.2.73", 60 * 1000); // 1 minute time out (in ms)
if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Server is up");
}
else
{
   Console.WriteLine("Server is down");
}
```

You can reduce the time out value to quickly check if server is up or down.

Comment: when I have done this in the console window nothing its showing , just its getting closed after the given time

Comment: thank you I have got the answer, just added console.readline and i was able to see the answer. thank you

Answer (score 2):

use this instead

```
Ping pingSender = new Ping ();
byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes ("test");
int timeout = 100;
PingReply reply = pingSender.Send("127.0.0.1", timeout, data);
if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Address: {0}", reply.Address.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("RoundTrip time: {0}", reply.RoundtripTime);
    Console.WriteLine("Time to live: {0}", reply.Options.Ttl);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to capture the output, check for the existence of time out string and then take the decision based on that.

[Capturing the Output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390559/how-to-get-the-output-of-a-system-diagnostics-process)