# How to crop a mp3 from x to x+n using ffmpeg?

Tags: mp3, ffmpeg, crop

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386818/how-to-crop-a-mp3-in-asp-net-c) I decided to use ffmpeg to crop MP3s. On [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43890/crop-mp3-to-first-30-seconds) I found this way of doing it:

```
ffmpeg -t 30 -acodec copy -i inputfile.mp3 outputfile.mp3
```

The problem is that I don't want to crop the first 30 seconds, I want to crop from x to x+n, like from 30s to 100s. How would I go and do this?

I'm reading the [man for ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-doc.html) but this is not really straightforward, especially since I just discovered about ffmpeg and I'm not familiar with audio/video editing softwares, so any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

Take a look at the -t and -ss arguments. They should do what you want.

> -t duration
>
> Restrict the transcoded/captured video
>   sequence to the duration specified in
>   seconds. hh:mm:ss[.xxx] syntax is also
>   supported.
>
> -ss position'
>
> Seek to given time position in seconds.
>   hh:mm:ss[.xxx] syntax is also supported.

For example, `ffmpeg -ss 30 -t 70 -i inputfile.mp3 -acodec copy outputfile.mp3` should do the trick for the range you mentioned (30s-100s).

Comment: I think this will not work now, the postion of -acodec matters so should be: ffmpeg -ss 30 -t 70 -i inputfile.mp3  -acodec copy  outputfile.mp3

Comment: it also appears that the `-i` option should be first

Comment: making the -i first will make it fail to skip to the first 30s, the -ss should always come before the -i

Comment: -t should come after -i.                                       ffmpeg -ss 30  -i inputfile.mp3 -t 70 -acodec copy outputfile.mp3

Answer (score 27):

To expand a bit on Michael Madsens' Answer:

I've found either of the following satisfactory for trimming my audio files:

- `ffmpeg -ss` <start position>`-t`<duration> `-i inputfile -c:a copy outputfile`
- `ffmpeg -ss` <start position>`-i inputfile -t`<duration> `-c:a copy outputfile`

*Note: `-acodec` is an alias for `codec:a` which can be specified also as `c:a`*

As specified in the [Main Options FFMPEG Documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Main-options)

`-t duration (input/output)`

- When used as an input option (before -i), limit the duration of data read from the input file.
- When used as an output option (before an output url), stop writing the output after its duration reaches duration.

`-ss position (input/output)`

- When used as an input option (before -i), seeks in this input file to position.
- When used as an output option (before an output url), decodes but discards input until the timestamps reach position.

`duration` and `position` follow the [Time Duration Syntax](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#time-duration-syntax) :

- `[-][HH:]MM:SS[.m...]` or `[-]S+[.m...][s|ms|us]`

*Side Note: An answer on [How to detect intervals of silence with FFMPEG](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36077309/2078851) may also be of interest.*

---

### Differences between seeking and duration as input or output

> Note that in most formats it is not possible to seek exactly, so ffmpeg will seek to the closest seek point before position. When transcoding and -accurate_seek is enabled (the default), this extra segment between the seek point and position will be decoded and discarded. When doing stream copy or when -noaccurate_seek is used, it will be preserved.

I did a couple Tests on the following file:

```
Input #0, mp3, from 'test16s.mp3':
  Duration: 00:00:16.20, start: 0.025057, bitrate: 128 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
```

Aligned the outputs in Audacity in comparison to the original and got the following:

- `ffmpeg -ss 3 -t 5 -i test16s.mp3 -c:a copy out.mp3`

  - Start: 3s+00756samples (3.017142857s)
  - End: 8s+02062samples (8.04675737s)
  - Duration : 5s+01306samples (5.029614512s)
- `ffmpeg -ss 3 -i test16s.mp3 -t 5 -c:a copy out.mp3`

  - Start: 3s+00756samples (3.017142857s)
  - End: 8s+00910samples (8.020634921s)
  - Duration : 5s+00154samples (5.003492063s)
- `ffmpeg -i test16s.mp3 -ss 3 -t 5 -c:a copy out.mp3`

  - **Warning**: This created a file that some mp3 decoders gave error on attempting to open.
  - Start: 2s+42184samples (2.956553288s)
  - End: 8s+01071samples (8.024285714s)
  - Duration : 5s+02987samples (5.067732426s)
- `ffmpeg -t 5 -i test16s.mp3 -ss 3 -c:a copy out.mp3`

  - **Warning**: This created a file that some mp3 decoders gave error on attempting to open.
  - Start: 2s+42184samples (2.956553288s)
  - End: 5s+02043samples (5.046326531s)
  - Duration : 2s+03959samples (2.089773243)

In an attempt to get to see the seek jump I found interesting results
using :

- `ffmpeg -ss`  <secs>  `-i test16s.mp3 -t 5 -c:a copy out.mp3`

  - <secs> = 3, 2.99, 2.98, 2.97

    - Start: 3s+00756samples (3.017142857s), Duration:5s+00154
  - <secs> = 2.96

    - Start: same as above, Duration: 4s+41951
  - <secs> = 2.95

    - Start: 2s+43704 (2.991020408), End:7s+42707 Duration:4s+43103
  - <secs> = 2.94,2.93

    - Start: same as above, Duration: 4s+41951
  - <secs> = 2.92

    - Start: 2s+42552 (2.964897959s), Duration: 4s+43103
- `ffmpeg -ss`  <secs>  `-t 5 -i test16s.mp3 -c:a copy out.mp3`

  - <secs> = 3

    - Start: 3s+00756 (3.017142857s), Duration:5s+01306 (5.029614512s)
  - <secs> = 2.99, 2.98, 2.97

    - Start: same, Duration: 5s+00155
  - <secs> = 2.96

    - Start: same, Duration: 4s+43103
  - <secs> = 2.95

    - Start: 2s+43704 (2.991020408), End:7s+43859 Duration:5s+00155
  - <secs> = 2.94,2.93

    - Start: same, Duration: 4s+43103
  - <secs> = 2.92

    - Start: 2s+42552 (2.964897959s), Duration: 5s+00155

Concluding that with a **Stream Copy**, appears as if the minimal seek resolution in my specific file ,*(Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s)*, was:

- Seek Step of : 1152 samples, 26.122449 ms
- Seek position Error of up to 70 ms

Comment: Nice explaination.
If anyone got error check this -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/63431041/7783718

Comment: Make sure to make `-i input.mp3` the first param of ffmpeg

Comment: Hi @Natim, thanks for your comment. Could you elaborate on why you recommend to make the input the first parameter?

Comment: When I used `ffmpeg -ss 59:05 -c:a copy -t 90 -i input.mp3 output.mp3` with ffmpeg 4.3.1 I encountered a `Unknown decoder 'copy'` which was fixed by putting the `-i` in first position (or at least before `-c:a copy`)

Comment: aha, yes, it has to do with the "option" `-c:a copy`, if you put `-c:a copy` before the definition of the input `-i input.mp` ffmpeg is attempting to force the decoder to the one that you have specified. `copy` is not a decoder but instructs ffmpeg to copy directly without decoding and re-encoding the the input file, this is why you need to specify it after defining the input file in the case of stream copying. [More info on copy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38381173/2078851)

Comment: what is `samples` number? etc `Start: 3s+(((00756samples))) (3.017142857s)`. This value causes the output to be inaccurate.

Comment: Hi Farzad, samples in this context is describing a specific point in time in samples instead of fractions of a second. The audio bit stream is sampled at 44100 Hz --> This means 44100 samples in a second.  3 seconds and 756 samples is the same as 3 seconds and 756/44100 seconds = 0.017142857 seconds . This was the exact position where the trimmed version started/ended with respect to the original.