# How to set a video's duration in FFMPEG?

Tags: ffmpeg

How can I limit the video duration for a given video? For example, if we are uploading one video that should not exceed more than 5 minutes, I need a command in FFMPEG.

Answer (score 66):

Use the -t option to specify a time limit:

```
`-t duration'
    Restrict the transcoded/captured video sequence to the duration specified in seconds. hh:mm:ss[.xxx] syntax is also supported.
```

http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html

Comment: How can we set the output duration to the same as input duration, like the possibilty in scale with -1?

Comment: Note: This needs to be placed somewhere in the middle of the command, like this: `ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -t 00:05:00 output.mp3`

Comment: how to calculate duration of time depending on drawtext text width scrolling ?

Answer (score 12):

Just to elaborate a bit further for more detailed use and examples.

As Specified in the [FFMpeg Docs](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Main-options)

---

- `-t duration` *(input/output)*

  - When used as an **input option** (before -i),

    - limit the duration of data read from the input file.
    - e.g. `ffmpeg` **`-t 5`** `-i input.mp3 testAsInput.mp3`

      - Will stop writing automatically after 5 seconds
  - When used as an **output option** (before an output url),

    - stop writing the output after its duration reaches duration.
    - e.g. `ffmpeg -i input.mp3` **`-t 5`** `testAsOutput.mp3`

      - Will stop writing automatically after 5 seconds
  - Effectively, in this use case the result is the same. See below for a more extended use case.
- `-to position` *(input/output)*

  - Stop writing the output or reading the input at position.
  - e.g. same as above but with `to` instead of `t`
- `duration` or `position`must be a time duration specification, as specified in the [ffmpeg-utils(1) manual.](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#time-duration-syntax)

  - `[-][HH:]MM:SS[.m...]` or `[-]S+[.m...][s|ms|us]`
- `-to` and `-t` are **mutually exclusive** and -t has priority.

---

### Example use as input option with multiple inputs

*Note: `-f pulse -i 1` is my system audio , `-f pulse -i 2` is my micrphone input*

Lets imagine I want to record both my microphone and speakers at the same time indefinetly.*(until I force a stop with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>)*

- I could use the [amix filter](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#amix) for example.

```
ffmpeg \
-f pulse -i 1 \
-f pulse -i 2 \
-filter_complex "amix=inputs=2" \
testmix.mp3
```

- Now lets imagine I only want to record the first 5 seconds of my system audio and always my microphone, again, until I *kill* the process with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>).

```
ffmpeg \
-t 5 -f pulse -i 1 \
-f pulse -i 2 \
-filter_complex "amix=inputs=2:duration=longest" \
testmix.mp3
```

*Note: `:duration=longest` amix option is the default anyway, so not really needed to specify explicitly*

- Now lets assume I want the same as above but limit the recording to 10 seconds. The following examples would satisfy that requirement:

```
ffmpeg \
-t 5 -f pulse -i 1 \
-t 10 -f pulse -i 2 \
-filter_complex "amix=inputs=2:duration=longest" \
testmix.mp3
```

```
ffmpeg \
-t 5 -f pulse -i 1 \
-f pulse -i 2 \
-filter_complex "amix=inputs=2:duration=longest" \
-t 10 testmix.mp3
```

*Note: With regards to start `position` searching/seeking [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65099636/2078851) with a bit of investigation I did, may also be of interest.*

Answer (score 5):

An example;

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=s=1920x1080 -loop 1 -i "input.png" -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=1920:-2[fg]; [0:v][fg]overlay=y=-'t*h*0.02'[v]" -map "[v]" -t 00:00:03 output.mp4
```

This sets the max time to 3 seconds. Note that the -t has to be just before the output file, if you set it at the start of this command, i.e. `ffmpeg -t ....` it will NOT work.

Comment: **`-t` can be both an input or output option** depending on placement location. If you place `-t` as an input option (before `-i`), then it will only apply to the particular input it precedes. So in your case would apply only to `-i color=s=1920x1080` unless you add another `-t` before `-i "input.png"`. Meanwhile, you are looping `input.png` indefinitely and overlaying it. overlay filter will not end with the shortest input unless you tell it to do so, such as `overlay=y=-'t*h*0.02':shortest=1`.