# How can I split an mp4 video with ffmpeg every time the volume is zero?

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, sh

I need to split a video into many smaller videos.
I have tried PySceneDetect and its 2 scene detection methods don't fit my need.

The idea is to trigger a scene cut/break every time the volume is very low, every time audio level is less than a given parameter. I think overall RMS dB volume level is what I mean.

The purpose is to split an mp4 video into many short videos, each smaller video with short dialog phrases.

So far I have a command to get the overall RMS audio volume level.

```
ffprobe -f lavfi -i amovie=01x01TheStrongestMan.mp4,astats=metadata=1:reset=1 -show_entries frame=pkt_pts_time:frame_tags=lavfi.astats.Overall.RMS_level,lavfi.astats.1.RMS_level,lavfi.astats.2.RMS_level -of csv=p=0
```

How can I get only the minimum values for RMS level and its corresponding frame or time?

And then how can I use ffmpeg to split the video in many videos on every frame that corresponds to a minimum RMS?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not quite familiar with this specific topic, But [this](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioChannelManipulation) may help.

Comment: Answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36074224/how-to-split-video-or-audio-by-silent-parts) might help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `silencedetect` audio filter and feed its debugging output to `segment` output format parameter.

Here is a ready-made script:

```
#!/bin/bash

IN=$1
OUT=$2

true ${SD_PARAMS:="-55dB:d=0.3"};
true ${MIN_FRAGMENT_DURATION:="20"};
export MIN_FRAGMENT_DURATION

if [ -z "$OUT" ]; then
    echo "Usage: split_by_silence.sh input_media.mp4 output_template_%03d.mkv"
    echo "Depends on FFmpeg, Bash, Awk, Perl 5. Not tested on Mac or Windows."
    echo ""
    echo "Environment variables (with their current values):"
    echo "    SD_PARAMS=$SD_PARAMS       Parameters for FFmpeg's silencedetect filter: noise tolerance and minimal silence duration"
    echo "    MIN_FRAGMENT_DURATION=$MIN_FRAGMENT_DURATION    Minimal fragment duration"
    exit 1
fi

echo "Determining split points..." >& 2

SPLITS=$(
    ffmpeg -nostats -v repeat+info -i "${IN}" -af silencedetect="${SD_PARAMS}" -vn -sn  -f s16le  -y /dev/null \
    |& grep '\[silencedetect.*silence_start:' \
    | awk '{print $5}' \
    | perl -ne '
        our $prev;
        INIT { $prev = 0.0; }
        chomp;
        if (($_ - $prev) >= $ENV{MIN_FRAGMENT_DURATION}) {
            print "$_,";
            $prev = $_;
        }
    ' \
    | sed 's!,$!!'
)


echo "Splitting points are $SPLITS"

ffmpeg -v warning -i "$IN" -c copy -map 0 -f segment -segment_times "$SPLITS" "$OUT"
```

You specify input file, output file template, silence detection parametres and minimum fragment size, it writes multiple files.

Silence detection parameters may need to be tuned:

- `SD_PARAMS` environment variable contains two parameters: noise tolerance level and minimum silence duration. Default value is `-55dB:d=0.3`.
- Decrease the `-55dB` to e.g. `-70dB` if some faint non-silent sounds trigger spitting when they should not. Increase it to e.g. `-40dB` if it does not split on silence because of there is some noise in it, making it not completely silent.
- `d=0.3` is a minimum silence duration to be considered as a splitting point. Increase it if only serious (e.g. whole 3 seconds) silence should be considered as real, split-worthy silence.
- Another environment variable `MIN_FRAGMENT_DURATION` defines amount of time silence events are ignored after each split. This sets minimum fragment duration.

The script would fail if no silence is detected at all.

There is a [refactored version on Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/vi/2fe3eb63383fcfdad7483ac7c97e9deb), but there was a problem with it for one user.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190054/discussion-between-vi-and-juan-pablo-fernandez).

Comment: Licence=MIT